# Ubuntu writes dots on its own (.)

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, suspend

It happens when I am not writing, when I use many apps at the same time and when I suspend the PC (Sometimes it just happens randomly at any time)

I already checked the key, I also cleaned it with compressed air, I have all writing aids disabled, I also disabled the keyboard, but it still happens

I also updated the BIOS, but it still happens

I am using Ubuntu 20.04-5.11.0-40-generic

It's a HP ProBook 440 G3 I5-6200U Skylake, Intel HD 520 (I don't have a dedicated video card) 12GB of Ram

Edit1: They appear wherever I am typing as if they are pressing the key even though I have disabled it in Xmodmap, but it is intermittent, sometimes they appear fast and other times slower

Edit2: I think I already found a way to express myself better.

The problem persists, whether or not the keyboard is connected

Comment: not enough detail.  Where do they get written? Why do you think they are coming from the keyboard?  Are they saved in files or just appear on the screen?  Are they on every terminal or just one?

Comment: They appear wherever I am typing as if they are pressing the key even though I have disabled it in Xmodmap, but it is intermittent, sometimes they appear fast and other times slower

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense.  You said originally that you "disabled the keyboard" but in your Edit1, you said they appear "whenever I am typing".  Perhaps you should revise what you wrote?

Comment: I think I already found a way to express myself better.


The problem persists, whether or not the keyboard is connected

Comment: forgive my bad english, I speak spanish